# How to add new line in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to add new line in yaml configuration file through ansible playbook using [lineinfile](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/modules.html#lineinfile). What I have tried till now.

```
#attempt-1
- name: "Configure Node River"
 lineinfile: "dest=/path/to/config.conf line='node.river: river_name'"
#attempt-2
- name: "Configure Node River"
 lineinfile: "dest=/path/to/config.conf state=present regexp='^' line='node.river: river_name'"
```

Also I have tried as per reference document.

```
# Add a line to a file if it does not exist, without passing regexp
- lineinfile: dest=/tmp/testfile line="192.168.1.99 foo.lab.net foo"
```

Can anyone guide me how to add new line which is not present in file. I know I can add End of the File by adding `regexp='' insertafter=EOF` in my `#attempt-1`. But I want to add above line in middle of the file.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you can use `insertafter=<regexp>`:

```
--- play.yml
- hosts: localhost                                                              
  gather_facts: False                                                           
  tasks:                                                                        
    - name: "Configure Node River"                                            
      local_action: 'lineinfile dest=/home/ig/test.conf
                     line="node.river: river_name" insertafter="first line"'
```

test.conf before:

```
first line
second line
```

test conf after:

```
first line
node.river: river_name
second line
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your suggestion. Yes I have checked `insertafter` option are there. But I am trying to add without check existing string.

Comment: @Roopendra Do you whant to add line even if it is already present?

Comment: No. If its not present in file.

Comment: @Roopendra I can't get what do you mean by the middle of the file. Tha exact middle?

Comment: Is there any way to add new line without any insert criteria. As per describe in doucment [#Add a line to a file if it does not exist, without passing regexp](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/modules.html#lineinfile)

Comment: But doesn't your #attempt-1 do it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43998/discussion-between-graphite-and-roopendra)